# Missing Files error ndk-build

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I have been trying real hard to get this working but ndk-build always gives me an error when I try to build my project using Cygwin. This is the error I get:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/work/android-ndk-r8d-windows/android-ndk-r8d/ndk-build
Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:opencv_java: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that ././../libs/armeabi/libopencv_java.so exists  or that its path is correct
/cygdrive/c/work/android-ndk-r8d-windows/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:43: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

I have tried almost everything but the error just does not go away. I am using OpenCV library in my native code to detect faces in an image and return it to the java code.

Anybody who has faced a similar problem or has any tips??

Comment: can you please show us your android.mk file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your Android.mk file at the `LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=` directive you have a filename mismatch.

That is, one of the .c or cpp files declared there is not present inside the jni directory or has a misspelling in the name.

Comment: i have the same problem. But it is not solved yet.. coz file name is right name.. plz help me @mnemonicflow